# Physical Datacenter Resilience

Tags: cassandra-2.1

I am deploying Apache Cassandra to sit behind an application which has consistency level hard coded to "QUORUM".  There is a requirement to have the C* cluster survive a total physical DC failure, and the cluster sits with 6 nodes split across these two physical sites.  The C* cluster config has two DCs, matching the physical split, with replication factor of 3 in each. The two DCs have zero latency between them, so could be considered as one logical site.  Given the consistency level of the app is hard coded to QUORUM, Ive tried various replication factors, and even created a single C* DC setup with all 6 nodes, but no matter what I try, our app fails when half the nodes fail.  Is there a configuration to allow the app to survive losing 3 of the 6 C* nodes?

Thanks for reading, I havent been able to find an answer through searching...

Answer (score 0):

Using QUORUM (= 4 for 6 node cluster ) will node help you to survive the 3 node failure.

If you set 3 replication on each DC and use consistency level **LOCAL_QUORUM** instead of QUOURM for reading and writing then you can survive entire DC failure + 1 node failure in local DC. i hope this is what you want.